# Numeric conversion to time has stop working in r

Tags: r, time, lubridate

I am having a new problem with numeric and time conversion in r. I have been parsing these variables in R, for the last two months, from numbers to time. Today, I get warning message stating: "some strings fail to parse". I have been using the lubridate library and it has been effort-less. Could it be R Studio acting up for a day?

data frame;

```
Rows: 413
Columns: 4
$ Id          double 1503960366, 1503960366, 1503960366, 1503…
$ date        chr "4/12/2016 12:00:00 AM", "4/13/2016 12:0…
$ time.asleep double 327, 384, 412, 340, 700, 304, 360, 325, …
$ time.in.bed double 346, 407, 442, 367, 712, 320, 377, 364, …
```

Comment: This is the code I have been using for months: 
sleep.day$time.asleep <- hms(sleep.day$time.asleep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you were using `lubridate::hms` and not `hms::hms` ?

```
lubridate::hms(327)

[1] NA
```

> Warning message:
> In .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :
> Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs

```
hms::hms(327)
#00:05:27
```

Or for entire column.

```
sleep.day$time.asleep <- hms::hms(sleep.day$time.asleep)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you!